# form mail with auto sequencial numbering

Tags: php

My problem is this,

we have a form that when filled will send an email to the company with all the form info, my boss is asking to add a sequential number (1,2,3,4) to the info on the email

I'm using the Mail function of PHP, they don't save the data on any DB so I can't pull an incremental field from there

Is there a way to do it via code only??

thanks for any help you can give me

Comment: best approach: store it in a database. alternatively, store it in a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can for example save it in a file:

```
$i = file_get_contents("number");
$i++;
file_put_contents("number", $i);
/* mail $i */
```

p.s.: but you have to store it somewhere; you can store it also in shared memory etc; but then the number will be lost on restart.

Comment: I was thinking on stored on a separate text file, the code above will read and increment right? how I rewrite the file with the new number?

Comment: From this one I get {"mailCount":0} how make the mailcount disappear?

Comment: forget my last comment... It worked! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Save the sequential number to a database (or less awesome: save it to a file). Then each time the form is loaded:

1. Read the number from the DB (or file) and send it along in the email
2. Increment the number
3. Save the newly incremented number to the DB (or file)

Comment: Rather use incremental and record every field if go with the BD approach but I'm looking to an alternative to BD so I was thinking on the file but not sure how to go about it (never worked with text files on php)

Comment: it's super easy to read/write from/to text files. Two functions you'll need: READ: file_get_contents()  WRITE:  file_put_contents()

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the information somewhere. One way of doing it would be to create a simple JSON encoded "text file db".

```
$dbFile = 'path/to/file';

// Load the data from the file
$db = @get_object_vars(json_decode(@file_get_contents($dbFile)));

...

// Update the counter
if (isset($db['mailCount'])) {
    $db['mailCount']++;
}
else {
    $db['mailCount'] = 0;
}

...

// Write the db file
$fp = fopen($dbFile, 'w+');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($db));
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Oh let me try this! thanks, brb

Comment: Make sure that PHP has permission to write to your file.

Comment: tried it but where it should be the number shows the word Array?